# How to shutdown my system via a php site using LAMP server?

Tags: php, lamp, shutdown, system-shutdown

This is the code i have so far

site:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['action']=="Shutdown") {
    $test=shell_exec("touch /scripts/shutdown.sh");
}
?>
```

shutdown.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -f "/tmp/shutdown" ]
then
   rm -f /tmp/shutdown
   /sbin/shutdown now
fi
```

I roughly got the idea from [http://ubuntuforums.org/](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1855905) But, when i run the php script on my local-host, it doesn't show up?

**Question**: *How to shutdown my system via a php site using LAMP server?*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "touch" doesn't execute a file (http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/touch/). If you want to execute your shellscript you should just do shell_exec("/scripts/shutdown.sh");. Be sure the path to the script is correct.

Comment: One needs to point out the fact that this could become a major security issue in a web application.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create a script for it, you can just do:

```
shell_exec('sudo /sbin/shutdown -h now');
```

Comment: I like that i don't have to use a external file. but I copy/paste the code between `<?php ... ?>` it doesn't show op in my localhost website, which is running php!

Answer (score 0):

`touch` only updates the file's modification time, it doesn't execute the script.

What you need to do is to give the user the PHP/web server process is running as the permission to execute the `shutdown` command, a permission typically reserved for root and not ordinary web processes. The best way is probably through the sudoers file, giving the user (probably `www-data` or so) the permission to execute `sudo shutdown` via `exec()` without password prompt. Read the `man sudoers` configuration for your system. Be extremely careful not to give permissions beyond this or to otherwise screw up your sudoers configuration.

The sudoers file needs an entry like:

```
www-data  ALL=NOPASSWD:  /sbin/shutdown
```

Again, read up on `man sudoers` to be sure what you're doing here. Only use `visudo` to edit the sudoers file to make sure it doesn't mess up.

Then:

```
exec('sudo /scripts/shutdown.sh');
```