# How to get a `background-color` effect when clicking on a `url#header4` link

Tags: html, css

How to get a `background-color` effect when clicking on a `url#header4` link

like for instance here on stackoverflow. if you would select this on:

[How to shutdown my system via a php site using LAMP server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643094/how-to-shutdown-my-system-via-a-php-site-using-lamp-server/17643147?noredirect=1#17643147)

That is a link with an `id` and when u click it you would go to that link, to that header, and get a fancy background affect with a fading effect.

how can i get that effect on my website?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868830/get-css-id-from-url

Comment: I rather not use jquery or javascript. Could this be accomplished, with just css3/html5. I'll wait till there is an answer. if not, then i'll check out the jquery/javascript options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using CSS 3 (Animation & keyframes). No javascript needed at all.

```
.targetbox:target {
    animation: 2s ease 0s normal none 1 trgt;
}

@keyframes trgt {
    0% { background: #ff3; }
    100% { background: #ffa; }
}

…
```

See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SCQev/1/